# ASP.NET (VB) Rowdatabound seeing all data as text not integar or decimal

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

First of all, be nice to me as this is my first time trying to do anything out of the VBA norm I'm used to.

I have a little reporting internet site setup and I have data stored in a DB (SQL Server 10.50.40000) and is stored as `Int` / `Varchar` / `decimal (18,2)`. I have created a webpage (VB) using Visual Web Dev 2010 to access this data and display it, however I cant do any formatting on the data as it for some reason I can only access to the data via `e.row.cells(COLUMNNUM).text` but when I try and `Parse` / `cast` / `CInt` / `TryParse` the info I get an error advising the input data isn't correct.

I've googled atleast 20 different versions of this but I cant find anything that works (90% of the questions are c# and I dont want (if I can help it)) for VB.

Codebehind (.aspx.vb):

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class FI7DayReport
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
    Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

        Dim testValue As String = e.Row.Cells(3).Text
        Dim today, today1, today2, today3, today4, today5, today6, today7, today8, today9 As Date
        Dim fiday As Integer

        today = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy")
        today1 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(+1).ToString("dd-MM-yy")
        today2 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(+2).ToString("dd-MM-yy")
        today3 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(+3).ToString("dd-MM-yy")
        today4 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(+4).ToString("dd-MM-yy")
        today5 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(+5).ToString("dd-MM-yy")
        today6 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(+6).ToString("dd-MM-yy")
        today7 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(+7).ToString("dd-MM-yy")
        today8 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(+8).ToString("dd-MM-yy")
        today9 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(+9).ToString("dd-MM-yy")

        For y = 3 To 9
            fiday = CInt(e.Row.Cells(y).Text)
            Integer.TryParse(e.Row.Cells(y).Text, fiday)
            If fiday > 44.9999999999999 Then


                e.Row.Cells(y).Attributes.Add("Style", "background-color: red;")
                e.Row.Cells(y).ForeColor = Color.Black


            End If

        Next

        If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header) Then
            e.Row.Cells(0).Visible = False
            e.Row.Cells(3).Text = today
            e.Row.Cells(4).Text = today1
            e.Row.Cells(5).Text = today2
            e.Row.Cells(6).Text = today3
            e.Row.Cells(7).Text = today4
            e.Row.Cells(8).Text = today5
            e.Row.Cells(9).Text = today6
            e.Row.Cells(10).Text = today7
            e.Row.Cells(11).Text = today8
            e.Row.Cells(12).Text = today9
        End If

        If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
            e.Row.Cells(0).Visible = False

            If e.Row.Cells(13).Text > "0" Then
                e.Row.Cells(13).Attributes.Add("Style", "background-color: red;")
                e.Row.Cells(13).ForeColor = Color.Black

            End If

            For x = 3 To 12
                If e.Row.Cells(x).Text = 0 Then

                    e.Row.Cells(x).Text = "Rest"      

                End If

            Next        
        End If        
    End Sub
End Class
```

Code (.ASPX):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="FI7DayReport.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.FI7DayReport" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
    &nbsp;

    <div><asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Width="110%" style="font-size: large; text-align: center;" 
        CellPadding="5" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
        HorizontalAlign="Center" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
        AllowSorting="True">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Payroll" HeaderText="Payroll" 
                SortExpression="Payroll" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Depot" HeaderText="Depot" 
                SortExpression="Depot" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateToday" HeaderText="DateToday" 
                SortExpression="DateToday" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateToday1" HeaderText="DateToday1" 
                SortExpression="DateToday1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateToday2" HeaderText="DateToday2" 
                SortExpression="DateToday2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateToday3" HeaderText="DateToday3" 
                SortExpression="DateToday3" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateToday4" HeaderText="DateToday4" 
                SortExpression="DateToday4" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateToday5" HeaderText="DateToday5" 
                SortExpression="DateToday5" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateToday6" HeaderText="DateToday6" 
                SortExpression="DateToday6" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateToday7" HeaderText="DateToday7" 
                SortExpression="DateToday7" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateToday8" HeaderText="DateToday8" 
                SortExpression="DateToday8" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateToday9" HeaderText="DateToday9" 
                SortExpression="DateToday9" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CountExceed" HeaderText="Exceedance Count" 
                SortExpression="CountExceed" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AvgFI" HeaderText="Avg FI" SortExpression="AvgFI" />
        </Columns>

        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />

    </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MelPerfTableConString %>"      


        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [FI_7DayReport2]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Might have just sorted it...testing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I didnt import SQL data and Data Client, and ASP net was just treating it as text / string data and didnt know what is was, also removed the " markers.